# How to find a previous weekday (Sunday, Monday, etc.) from a specific date using Momentjs

Tags: momentjs, weekday

I'm trying to figure out how to build code that will find the 'MM/DD/YYYY' date of a previous day of the week in relation to a given date, which is 04/10/18.

If I've understood Momentjs' [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) correctly, I think I can use negative weekday numbers to find a past 'X-day' from a specific date.

I know the date I'm using is a Tuesday, so I thought if I gave the weekday function the numerical representation of last Tuesday (-2), I would get the past Tuesday, '04/03/2018'. The problem is that when I run the following check:

```
expect(await moment('04/10/2018', ['MM/DD/YYYY']).weekday(-2).format('MM/DD/YYYY')).toBe('04/03/2018');
```

I get a result of '04/06/2018' instead.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is correct.  The function .weekdays(-2) computes two weekdays earlier than the given moment.

In your example, two weekdays before a Tuesday would be a Friday, because one weekday before Tuesday is Monday, and one weekday before that is Friday, so Tuesday 4/10/2018 - 2 weekdays = Friday 4/06/2018.